# How to subtract two tables with different number of columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have made two tables with different number of columns in each and two column names are same in both the tables. How can i use MINUS operator for this ??? help

Comment: Subtract what from what?  Do you have samples you can provide us?  Who would win in a fight between a grilled cheese sandwich and a taco?

Comment: Im guessing you need all the common columns?

Comment: C'mon @Linger, everyone knows it is the grilled cheese sandwich.

Comment: There we go talking about food again. Now you've done it; I've got the "Munchies". @JayBlanchard and Linger.

Comment: Well, a silly incomplete question deserves a silly comment.

Comment: They make an ointment for that.

Comment: Er, taco. Every time.

Comment: You're obviously not getting the right grilled cheese @Strawberry

Comment: I take it that, it won't be long till there's a "food fight", or just fight for food ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Think about it. Hot sauce and guacamole vs. Monterey Jack. How's that even fair?

Comment: I will share one grilled cheese sandwich for every UV my meager answer receives. Mine *and* Linger's. And we'll give one to Strawberry too, even though he is fixated on hot sauce and guacamole. Wait...hot sauce and guacamole? Tacos for everyone! Ariba!

Comment: Well I didn't realize the food comment would generate such a discussion.  You do realize it is from [**Hot Rod**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0787475/) which is a hilarious movie.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like:

```
SELECT t1.field1 - t2.field1 AS Field1Diff,
       t1.field2 - t2.field2 AS Field2Diff,
       t1.field3 - t2.field3 AS Field3Diff,
       and blah blah blah etc
FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.sameField1 = t2.sameField 
                      AND t1.sameField2 = t2.sameField2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is like this -

```
SELECT `table1`.`foo` - `table2`.`foo` AS `fooTotal`
FROM `table1`, `table2`
```

But you're likely to have other issues that we cannot predict because we have not seen your table schema or any other details that are needed to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not provide support for the `MINUS` set operator, so you won't be able to use that.

Likely what you want is an anti-join pattern. Return all rows from one table that don't have a 'matching' row in another table.

As a demonstration:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, fum VARCHAR(10));
 INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'d'),(2,'e'),(3,'f');

 CREATE TABLE bar (id INT);
 INSERT INTO bar VALUES (2),(3),(3),(3);
```

Ant-join pattern is a LEFT JOIN to return all rows from `a` along with any matching rows from `b`, and then exclude any rows that had a match from `b`. For example:

```
 SELECT a.id
      , a.fum
   FROM foo a
   LEFT
   JOIN bar b
     ON b.id = a.id
  WHERE b.id IS NULL
```